# I get this error in Gaussian09 even though I have enough memory. "Error termination in NtrErr: NtrErr called from FIOCnC." Any suggestions?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, gaussian, coupled-cluster

Whenever read-write files get to about 20Gb, I get this error. I know that, in G09, one rw file  is limited to 16Gb. So I have set the software to write several RWFs. But it still keeps producing this error...
My input line and rwf line look like this:

```
%rwf=1,15000mb,2,15000mb,3,13000mb

#p opt freq=noraman rccsd/genecp nosymm
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: +1. Thanks for asking here, and good luck getting a quick answer! It's been years since I used Gaussian so hopefully a more frequent Gaussian user can help you.

Comment: In general this error is due to lack of memory and/or disk space. Try to increase the memory in your input (using %mem=5Gb, for example). Also, are you able to create such "big" files? I mean, there are some hard disk partition types that not support single files greater that 2GB.

Comment: @Camps G09 often writes rw files a lot bigger than 2 Gb on my PC.

As for %mem=5Gb, I'm short on RAM...

Comment: Maybe your RAM limitation is causing the problem.

Comment: You could probably post the update as a self-answer instead.

Comment: I am down voting this question, because it is not really useful. It would need a full input file, complete version specification, OS, available resources (at least).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, splitting the scratch files doesn't help. I have a 32-bit version of Gaussian, and it has a 16Gb limit for the combined size of the scratch files (I don't know how I could miss that). So splitting the read-write file can't help here. Looks like I'll have to find better computational resources.

Comment: Consider upgrading to a new version, and if you want efficient CC, then maybe look into other programs. I'm sure there is already a q&a here for this.

Comment: The question is quite old, but maybe it would be better to use #T instead of #P?